# How to use twig macro inside controller?

Tags: templating, modules, controller, macro

I want to use the `macro` I defined in `twig` inside a `controller` or a `module`.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, macros can only be included from within Twig. But you can create a simple wrapper template and render that:

```twig
{# my-macro.twig #}

{% macro my_macro(foo = 'bar') %}
    <p>{{ foo }}</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

```twig
{# path/to/macro-wrapper.twig #}

{% from "my-macro.twig" import my_macro %}
{% set foo = foo ?? 'default' %}
{{ my_macro(foo) }}
```

You can use `View::renderTemplate` to render the wrapper template:

```php
/** @var \craft\web\View */
$view = Craft::$app->getView();

$view->renderTemplate('path/to/macro-wrapper.twig', [
    'foo' => 'baz'
], \craft\web\View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP);
```